# Handling of div clones between web page, server and database as required by user interaction

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, json

I have written this script for users to clone the `div="test hidden"` as many times as needed. Within each `div` there are some user input, `class="user_input1"`, as well as some checkboxes `class="user_input2"`. There are two catches to this script:

1. The input should be systematically inserted into the database for each `div="test hidden"` that is cloned and appended. For example if there are three input1's with different values, three rows should be created with each respective value. This catch has been solved and works quite nicely. But now the second catch:
2. The check boxes in `class="user_input2"` are added to the page based on the content of database 1. This is so that users can add the names of the tests that will be available for selection in the web page, without having to actually modify the html code and add columns to the MySQL database. If a check box is selected, the id of the corresponding test will be saved to the database along with the input of `class="user_input1"`. Later, these id's can be called again and referenced to their corresponding test names. These id's are saved as part of a JSON text to save the selected tests as a array in a single entry of the same row in the database, and should do so for each row.

Here is my problem: Due to the cloning of the div's and the server script accounting for the multiple cloned entries, the check box selected id's are not inserted correctly into the database. If you made three clones, all three clones' check box id's are inserted into each database entry. I think it has to do with the server script and require some nested function, but I am new with php and not sure what I am doing wrong.

Please feel free to use the code below to try it on your machines.

SQL for database 1 creation and some entries:

```
CREATE TABLE `envirocare`.`database1` ( `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `checkb` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `database1` (`id`, `checkb`) VALUES (NULL, 'test1'), (NULL, 'test2')
```

SQL for database 2 creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `envirocare`.`database2` ( `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `input1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `input2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `checkbox` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The HTML script:

```
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<body>

    <button id="add">Add</button>

    <div class="test hidden">       

        <div class="input1">
            <label>Input1</label>
            <input class="input1" type="text" name="value1[]" value="1" required>
            <label>Input2</label>
            <input type="text" name="value2[]" required>

            <div class="input2">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Pick Option</th>                    
                        </tr>                                   
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                 
                        <?php
                        if ($resultCheck01 > 0) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) { ?>   
                                <tr> 
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['checkb']; ?></td>                              
                                </tr>                   
                            <?php } } ?> 
                        </tbody>
                    </table>        
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <form action="server/server.php" method="POST">
            <div class="paste">     
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="insert_res">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var variable = 0
                $("#add").click(function() {
                    var element = $(".test.hidden").clone(true);
                    element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste:last");
                    variable++;
                    $(".input1:last").val(variable);

                });
            });
```

And finally the server side:

```
$sql01 = "SELECT * FROM database1";
$result01 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql01);
$resultCheck01 = mysqli_num_rows($result01);



if (isset($_POST['insert_res'])) {  
    $n = count($_POST['value1']);
    for($i = 0; $i<$n; ++$i) {
        $value1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['value1'][$i]);
        $value2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['value2'][$i]);


        $encode = json_encode($_POST['check']);
        $check = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $encode);



        $query = "INSERT INTO database2 (input1, input2, checkbox) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$check')";    

        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }   

    header("Location: ../test.php?success");
}
```

When using `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die;` this is what is displayed:

```
Array
(
    [value1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [value2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello
            [1] => World
        )

    [check] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
        )

    [insert_res] => 
)
```

So the check part should look like this:

```
    [check] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1,3
            [1] => 1,2
        )

    [insert_res] => 
)
```

Comment: can you show us what is inside `$_POST` if you have f.e. 3 clones?
(`echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die;`)

Comment: I am not sure where to enter this in my code? Could you point me in the correct direction please?

Comment: You can do it right after the `if(isset($_Post['insert_res'])){`

Comment: I have a similar issue, some answers to this question will be much appreciated!!

Comment: @toffler please see the update!

Comment: You can not just use `name="foo[]"` everywhere in such a situation. Checkboxes only create an entry in the form data set, if they are checked - otherwise, they are left out. So you will lose the correlation to your other input fields in such a case. If you specify the index upfront (`name="foo[0]"`, `name="foo[1]"` etc.), you can avoid that problem - but you would need to modify your client-side cloning function accordingly.

Comment: Let me see if I can try this.. good point!

Comment: So... I guess I still don't understand what you wan't to do properly.
Maybe you can post some pictures for visual understanding?

I just came up with a workaround that woud do it for this example and maybe it's what you are looking for, however - it's not very beautiful.

Comment: ` $val1 = array(1,2);
        $val2 = array("Hello","World");
        $check = array(1,3,1,2);
        $check2 = array();
        
        $x = -1;
        foreach($check as $k=>$tmp)
        {
            if($k % count($val1) == 0)
            {
                $x++;
            }       
            
            if(!isset($check2[$x])) $check2[$x] = "";
            $check2[$x] .= $tmp.",";
        }

        foreach($check2 as $k=>$tmp)
        {
            $check2[$k] = substr($tmp,0,-1);
        }`

afterwards you can `json_encode` ur check2

Comment: paste this code before `$encode = json_encode($_POST['check']);` and replace `$check` for `$_POST['check']` ... also use your `$value1` and 2 instead of my static array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post the summary of my comments here, because of the character limitations.

I came up with a workaround for your problem, however it's not very beautiful and I cannot guarantee that it will work for all cases because I still don't properly understand what you wan't to do - but I hope it will still help you.

I generated 3 static arrays to simulate your input's and checkboxes:

```
    $val1 = array(1,2);
    $val2 = array("Hello","World");
    $check = array(1,3,1,2);
    $check2 = array();
```

Afterwards I generate a new output array `$check2` and formate it according to your request:

```
    $x = -1;
    foreach($check as $k=>$tmp)
    {
        if($k % count($val1) == 0)
        {
            $x++;
        }       

        if(!isset($check2[$x])) $check2[$x] = "";
        $check2[$x] .= $tmp.",";
    }

    foreach($check2 as $k=>$tmp)
    {
        $check2[$k] = substr($tmp,0,-1);
    }
```

The output of `$check2` is:

```
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1,3"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "1,2"
  }
```

You can `json_encode` it and do your query afterwards.
I really hope this helps you, please let me know about it

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not having any luck. Is there no way to use `json_encode` before adding it to the array perhaps?

Comment: You need to encode and query the `$check2`, not `$check`

Comment: Could you please tell me in the context of my php script where this should be implemented, I am confused with this and the `for` function in my own script?

Comment: Ah I see... you have to generate your `$check2` array before the for-loop. use `foreach($_POST['check'] as $k=>$tmp)`. In your loop you do  `$check = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $check2[$i]);`

Comment: The static arrays, do I have to replace them with my input arrays?

Comment: you replace them with your `$_POST` data ...my `$val1` is your `$_POST['value1']` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173874/discussion-between-mariska-and-toffler).